# Switching to non-debug runtime /MT causes link errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I'm trying to deploy my executable to another machine so I need non-debug runtime.

Switching to non-debug runtime /MT causes link errors. /Mtd compiles fine. Here's a sampling of the many errors.

> 1>libcpmtd.lib(_tolower.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _calloc_dbg
>   1>libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _calloc_dbg
>   1>libcpmtd.lib(wlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _calloc_dbg
>   1>libcpmtd.lib(StlCompareStringA.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
>   1>libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
>   1>libcpmtd.lib(wlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
>   1>libcpmtd.lib(xlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
>   1>libcpmtd.lib(xwcsxfrm.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg

If I explicitly tell linker to link with libcmtd.lib, it compiles even with /MT, but what are the consequences of this?

How do I get my code to compile? (without having to do the trick above?)

Edit: I commented out the statements using cout and it compiled.... why...

Comment: Looks like you forced the memory allocator to use the degug version somewhere. Look for a pesky _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC define in your code, or maybe some other similar trick for older MSVC versions.

Comment: libcpmtd.lib is the multi-threaded debug C++ DLL.  At a guess you have one .obj file built in release, and another built in debug.  This causes references to both the release and debug libraries to be included, and whichever one the linker checks first is the one it uses for other symbols that can be found in the lib.  You get errors when it chose the debug C++ lib and the release CRT lib.  Commenting out `cout` changes the order the libraries get searched, and explicitly using libcmtd.lib causes it to use the debug CRT before the release one.  Be sure everything is compiled in release.

Comment: This worked for me: Set the Debug configuration to /MTd, and the Release to /MT

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 10):

Remove _DEBUG define from C++ preprocessor

Comment: was having too much errors. As I changed mode to release, and all errors went out. +1

Answer (score 9):

You say you explicitly force libcmtd.lib as linker input - that is the *debug* version of the static CRT, and is exactly the source of the conflict with /MT (a switch declaring linkage with the *release* static CRT).

Remove libcmtd from the linker input altogether and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In may case, my application was use /MT, and my libcpmtd.lib build without /MT. Switch to the same resolve the issue.